# Python TypeError: len() of unsized object

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have an error when trying to draw a chart using matplotlib.

`TypeError: len() of unsized object`

```
def obj_func(x,y):
    suma=(x*m.sin(m.sqrt(abs(x)))+y*m.sin(m.sqrt(abs(y))))
    y=418.9829*2 - suma
    return y
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
wykres = plt.figure()
ax = wykres.gca(projection='3d')
x=np.arange(-1.5,1.5,0.25)
y=np.arange(-1.5,1.5,0.25)
x,y=np.meshgrid(x,y)
z = np.vectorize(obj_func)
zz=z(x,y)
ax.set_xlabel('OS x')
ax.set_ylabel('OS Y')
ax.set_zlabel('f(x,y)')
ax.plot_surface(x, y, zz ,50, cmap='binary')
wykres.suptitle('Wykres f(x,y)')
plt.show()
```

Comment: pelase repost the question with the error message and minimal code required to generate the error.

Comment: Without a stack trace it is impossible to debug this.

Comment: Please reduce and enhance this into the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  At the very least, we expect you to remove the inapplicable code, fix the undefined symbols, supply the *full* error message (with trace-back), and make an attempt to diagnose the problem yourself -- at least print the values of the offending variables.

Comment: Also, please explain why you're trying to plot a series against a constant.  Read the documentation for `plot_surface` to make sure you're supplying the required arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this :

```
ax.plot_surface(x, y, zz ,cmap='binary', linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
```

The problem is caused by `50`